# How dangerous is this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, delete-file, nohup

**WARNING:** Dangerous script. Do not run from your command line!

Saw this in a company joke email. Can someone explain to me why this bash script is more dangerous than a normal 'rm -rf' command?:

```
nohup cd /; rm -rf * > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Particularly, why is nohup used and what are the elements at the end for?

**WARNING:** Dangerous script. Do not run from your command line!

Comment: This is only very marginally a programing question

Comment: `--no-preserve-root` (whistling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2>&1` takes stderr (file handle 2) and redirects to stdout (file handle 1). `&` by itself places the rm command in the background. nohup allows a job to keep running even after the person who started it logs out.

In other words, this command does its best to wipe out the entire file system, even if the user ragequits their terminal/shell.

Comment: "file handle" aka "file descriptor"

Comment: Fortunately, the script's best is not as bad as its author wanted. He or she was so scared of his/her own idea that he/she did not test it :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can try something less "dangerous":

```
nohup cd /; find * >/dev/null 2>&1  &
```

I'm getting this:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: cannot run command `cd': No such file or directory
[2] 16668
```

So, `nohup` part does nothing, it only triggers an error. The second part (of the original script) tries to remove everything in your current directory, and cannot be stopped by <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, because it runs in the background. All its output is redirected to void, so you do not see any 'access denied' progress messages.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'nohup cd /' ?

Comment: +1 If the OP's command were `cd /; nohup ...` there would be no error message from `nohup`.

Comment: Why is this upvoted?  nohup does not trigger an error.  It detaches from the terminal so that you can close your terminal and the process will continue.

Comment: @DGM: Have you tried it? What version of shell and `nohup` do you have?

Comment: As a system administrator of an ISP for many years, I have used nohup a lot.  It does what I said.   Running this command on a mac with bash does exactly what I'd expect - backgrounds a find, and silences all output.  It could be the shell or os you are using that made it fail for you.  In any case, this is a discussion for another site.

Comment: BTW, if anyone runs this command, it will churn your disk until it has looked at every file.  Not destructive, but it will slow your computer down.   use `ps ax | grep find` to find the PID of the process, and then `kill 12345` to kill it.  (with the correct pid, of course)

Comment: @DGM: `find` is silenced by redirections and backgrounded by `&`. Nohup is not a shell builtin, therefore it cannot accept a builtin as an argument. The script is a citation from http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/02/24/bofh_2006_episode_8/

Answer (score 3):

The joke is kind of broken, obviously it has not been tested, he meant

```
 nohup sh -e "cd / ; rm -rf *" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or

```
 nohup rm -rf / > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

otherwise the nohup cd /; part is considered one separate line by the shell. and the second line just spawn rm -rf * which recursively rm your current directory (less the files with name started with . )

Answer (score 2):

`nohup [..] &` makes it run in the background even after the user has logged out (making it harder to stop, I suppose)

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout

`> /dev/null` discards anything coming from stdout

The command would basically appear to do nothing, as your filesystem slowly gets destroyed in the background.

Answer (score 2):

nohup means that it will ignore the hangup signal, meaning that it will keep running even if the user is no longer signed in.

cd / moves the user to the root directory

rm -rf * removes all files recursively(traverses all directories) and forcefully(doesn't care if files are in use)

The piece on the end redirects all output to nowhere. It should essentially format your drive to nothing.

Comment: You would have gotten top answer if you elaborated on the redirects a little more. Also you didn't mention the backgrounding '&' at the end. Good answer though.